How to collapse/un-nest an Array[File] output in WDL workflow?
I am running a WDL workflow.
Here is the output block in the main workflow
    output {
        Array[File] out_foos = some_task.foos
    }

Let's say that array had three elements.
The output files would then look like this:
/path/to/out/out_foos/00/fooA.txt
/path/to/out/out_foos/01/fooB.txt
/path/to/out/out_foos/02/fooC.txt

How do I change it so that the output is less nested so it instead looks like this:
/path/to/out/out_foos/fooA.txt
/path/to/out/out_foos/fooB.txt
/path/to/out/out_foos/fooC.txt

My preference is to make this happen with the workflow. I would also be open, however, to just moving the files after the workflow finishes, but this workflow is being submitted to aws with aws omics start-run so it's not clear to me how to do that either
